# How do I resolve the overlap in fviz_pca_biplot in factoextra packages

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel, factoextra

In the following command, whose shape output is also known, I have the problem of overlap in the specified area. I want all correlation lines to have labels without overlapping.

I used the geom_label_repel command, but I got an error.

```
fviz_pca_biplot(PCA.Res01, # Individuals
                                    geom.ind = "point",
                                    fill.ind = DataPCA01$CitysNumb,
                                    pointshape = 21, pointsize = 1,
                                    palette = "ucscgb",
                                    repel = TRUE,
                                    addEllipses = TRUE,
                                    ellipse.level=0.95,
                                    labelsize = 6, # Variables
                                    col.var = "contrib",
                                    gradient.cols = c("blue", "red", "black"), ggtheme = theme_minimal())+
  labs(fill = "Citys", color = "Correlation", caption = "(Logical Value = 0.95)")+ # Change legend title
  theme(text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14, face = 'bold'),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14, face = 'bold'))
```

Output:
[image: graph output]

I applied the following command:

```
+ geom_label_repel(aes(label = names, label.size = 6), min.segment.length = 0.5)
```

But it was not done and it showed the following error:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type <function>. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in `geom_label_repel()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 10th layer.
Caused by error in `compute_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics are not valid data columns.
✖ The following aesthetics are invalid:
✖ `label = names`
ℹ Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add `after_stat()`?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning message:
In geom_label_repel(aes(label = names, label.size = 6), min.segment.length = 0.5):
   Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label.size
```

I know that the above command cannot be used.

My question is, is there another command that can change the overlay more easily and conveniently?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: This is impossible. I just need help. thank you.

Comment: You do not need to share your data, just make up some data that gives the same error. 
The error message tells you there is no column called `names` in  whatever data.frame `ggplot` was passed as argument for `data`.  You can investigate this by running the first part of the code (until before the first `+`) saving this into a variable, let's say `p`, then run `colnames(p$data)` or just `p$data` to see what is the data available to ggplot layer functions.  Function `fviz_pca_biplot()` creates a `gg` object, but is likely modifying its input before plotting.